# Custom Error Queue Name when using EasyNetQ for RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, easynetq

Rather than having my unhandled exceptions go into **EasyNetQ_Default_Error_Queue** I wondered if there is a way that I can explicitly state the name of an Error Queue that should be used for a given application, so errors don't ALL end up in this one **EasyNetQ_Default_Error_Queue**?

I can see how to specify regular message queue names but haven't managed to find anything about Error Queue names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can customize the naming conventions by overriding the delegates on the IConventions object (or just create your own implementation of it and register that as a dependency):

https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/master/Source/EasyNetQ.Tests/ConventionsTests.cs

This should probably work:

```
var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost");
bus.Advanced.Container.Resolve<IConventions>().ErrorExchangeNamingConvention = info => "MyExchangeNaming";
bus.Advanced.Container.Resolve<IConventions>().ErrorQueueNamingConvention = () => "MyErrorQueueNaming";
```

Comment: Thanks Zidad. Works great. My only issue after doing this is now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738683/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-different-error-queue-when-using-easynetq-hosepipe