# Is there a way to specify a different Error Queue when using EasyNetQ.Hosepipe?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, easynetq

I recently posted the following question...

[Custom Error Queue Name when using EasyNetQ for RabbitMQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696339/custom-error-queue-name-when-using-easynetq-for-rabbitmq/28716620#28716620)

... and was provided with a solution on how to use different, application specific Error Queue names when using EasyNetQ, rather than having all unhandled exceptions go into the default error queue (EasyNetQ_Default_Error_Queue).

What I'd now like is to be able to use EasyNetQ.Hosepipe.exe to dump all of the error messages from whichever Error queue I specify, as its default behaviour when doing the following, as per the documentation...

```
EasyNetQ.Hosepipe.exe err s:localhost o:C:\temp\messages
```

... is to dump any messages from the EasyNetQ_Default_Error_Queue, into a folder, and in my case, this default error queue will always be empty now.

Previously, when using the default error queue, I could use the above hosepipe err method, then use hosepipe retry...

```
EasyNetQ.Hosepipe.exe retry s:localhost u:guest p:guest o:C:\temp\messages
```

... and it would put all of the dumped error messages back into their respective queues for re-processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the q: parameter?

```
EasyNetQ.Hosepipe.exe dump s:localhost u:guest p:guest q:my_queue o:C:\temp\messages
```

I haven't used hosepipe, but this is from the usage.txt in the hosepipe project:

https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/master/Source/EasyNetQ.Hosepipe/Usage.txt

UPDATE:
HosePipe now supports a 'q' parameter to read from error queues that don't use the standard naming convention:

https://github.com/nvmlabs/EasyNetQ/commit/7945ff0f2c9d2e17088f109a542219fb5b11c3ab

Comment: Yes I did but q: doesn't appear to work in conjunction with err, and if I use dump, it doesn't have the same end result - I can't use a retry against a dump, and if I try an insert from a dump, it doesn't put the message back on it's original queue.

Comment: Ah ok sorry, perhaps a pull request? alternatively you can post this in the google group, maybe someone will pick it up...